# How to open in current window of ie - c#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, url

I'm trying to open something in ie via

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("iexplore.exe", uniquePartOfUrl);
```

However this doesn't account for the fact a window is already open, if it is then I want to just use that. How could this be done?

Comment: Why you need a window handle? IE's API is COM, if you want to control the new window/tab you should ask for IWebBrowser2 (though you can get the window/tab handle from IWebBrowser2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On CodeProject, there exists a project to "[Capturing the Running IE Instances in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/runninginstanceie.aspx)"

It gives you one way to do it.

Using the WIN32 API, you can enumerate the windows opened, and filter them to get the running instances of IE.

It may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, the best way to open a web page is to use the following syntax:

```
Process.Start("http://www.mysite.com");
```

This way the OS will open it in the users default browser, and use the browsers tab functionality if it has that capability. Nothing annoys me more (ok, maybe some things do) than programs that force me to use a specific browser for no good reason, when I already selected which browser I want to use already. Honoring the users decision here is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
var s = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(uniquePartOfUrl);
s.UseShellExecute = true;
s.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
p.StartInfo = s;
p.Start();
```

I don't have a compiler handy to test it right now, but the idea is that it should simply tell the OS to "open this URL" and let the OS decide how, which may use the existing window depending on the application.  Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

For reusing an existing window of IE, you can approach it in 2 different ways

1. Find the current instance of IE and then open it using that instance. This is covered by the answer given by @LaGrandMere
2. Set IE using the inbuilt settings to make it reuse itself. For using this method, you can follow the instructions given at [this Microsoft support article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=241911).